# PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given

Tags: php, sql, pdo

When I want to update my articles table from MySQL database I get the following error

```
PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given in /Users/Iceson/Sites/blog jean/app/Database.php on line 49
```

Here the update code from my managementpost.php

```php
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

$id = $_POST['id'];
$titre = $_POST['titre'];
$contenu = $_POST['contenu'];

App\App::getDb()->prepare("UPDATE articles SET titre ='$titre', 
contenu ='$contenu' WHERE id='id'",true);

}
```

Here is the my database class from my database.php, the error is located on the line `$req->execute($attributes);` in the function `prepare`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use \PDO;

class Database {

private $db_name;
private $db_user;
private $db_pass;
private $db_host;
private $pdo;

public function __construct($db_name, $db_user = 'root', $db_pass = 'root', $db_host = 'localhost') {

    $this->db_name = $db_name;
    $this->db_user = $db_user;
    $this->db_pass = $db_pass;
    $this->db_host = $db_host;
}

private function getPDO() {
    if ($this->pdo === null) {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blogdejean;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    } 
    return $this->pdo;   
}

public function query($statement, $class_name = null, $one = false) {
    $req = $this->getPDO()->query($statement);
    if($class_name === null) {
        $req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    } else {
        $req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class_name);
    }
    if($one) {
        $datas = $req->fetch();
    } else {
        $datas = $req->fetchALL();
    }
    return $datas;
}

public function prepare($statement, $attributes, $class_name = null, $one = false) {
    $req = $this->getPDO()->prepare($statement);
    $req->execute($attributes);
    if($class_name === null) {
        $req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    } else {
        $req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class_name);
    }
    if($one) {
        $datas = $req->fetch();
    } else {
        $datas = $req->fetchALL();
    }
    return $datas;
}
}
```

Comment: Your prepare statement failed. Check for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to find out why.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using PDO, take advantage of [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: Why do you use inline-variables in your query **and** prepared statements? Shouldn't the second method help you to skip the first?

Answer (score 1):

You are using your database class wrong: Instead of sending a statement with parameters you can bind, you inject the values in the sql statement making your query vulnerable to sql injection.

And where you need to send an array of values to bind, you send a boolean.

So you need to replace this:

```
App\App::getDb()->prepare("UPDATE articles SET titre ='$titre', contenu ='$contenu' WHERE id='id'",true);
```

with:

```
App\App::getDb()->prepare(
    "UPDATE articles SET titre = ?, contenu = ? WHERE id = ?",
     [
        $_POST['titre'], 
        $_POST['contenu'], 
        $_POST['id'],
    ]
);
```

You should probably also re-think why you are extending PDO like that; fetching all rows does not make sense on an update statement for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function prepare($statement, $attributes, $class_name = null, $one = false) {
    $req = $this->getPDO()->prepare($statement);
    $req->execute($attributes);
    if($class_name === null) {
        $req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    } else {
        $req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class_name);
    }
    if($one) {
        $datas = $req->fetch();
    } else {
        $datas = $req->fetchALL();
    }
    return $datas;
}
```

You prepare method expects a array as the second argument ($attributes), but you passed it `true`.

```
App\App::getDb()->prepare("UPDATE articles SET titre ='$titre', contenu ='$contenu' WHERE id='id'",true);
```

It should be something like this.

```
App\App::getDb()->prepare("UPDATE articles SET titre = :titre, contenu = :contenu WHERE id= :id",[':titre' => $titre, ':contenu' => $contenu, ':id' => $id ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks y'all now i  have a general error "General error in /Users/Iceson/Sites/blog jean/app/Database.php:58" it's the $datas = $req->fetchALL(); i think i messed up my database class everything was working until the update part, i don't know what's wrong

Comment: Update statements don't return data so you can't use `fetchALL()` or `fetch()` on them

Comment: thanks it works now, i used $res = $req->execute($attributes);
        if (strpos($statement, 'UPDATE') === 0 || strpos($statement, 'INSERT') === 0 || strpos($statement, 'DELETE') === 0) {
            return $res;
        } so it doesn't use the fetch when update

Comment: that's an awful crutch to be honest. why not to have method for non-select queries instead?

Comment: prepare and query methods could be merged into one

Comment: i'm not that good with php, i'm a student, i'm learning so that's why code is not on point